# NiFi: Routing on File Types, e.g. csv, tsv, xlsx

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a connected SFTP server, and I am trying to route files based on type: `.csv`, `.tsv`, and `.xlsx`. For now, I'm just uploading test files through the command line.

My flow is:

```
GetSFTP (with correct hostname, etc.) ->
RouteOnAttribute ->
LogAttribute (will dump elsewhere soon, this is just for testing)
```

My problem, I think, is that I created a property in `RouteOnAttribute` incorrectly:

[image: fetchcsv: <code>${filename:contains('.csv')}</code>]

Am I correct in assuming that this does not actually pick up on the `.csv` because it is not technically part of the filename? What would be the correct expression to route on the file type? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need some information that will tell you the type of file.

GetSFTP should be getting the filename from the file on the sftp server, so if those have the appropriate extensions then I would expect your RouteOnAttribute to work correctly.

If the filename does not have the appropriate extension, then the only thing you can do is try to use IdentifyMimeType to determine what type of file it is, and then route on the mime.type attribute.

Comment: Is GetSFTP deprecated? Should I be using the List/FetchSFTP combo instead? What I'm seeing: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/97773/how-to-retrieve-files-from-a-sftp-server-using-nif.html

Comment: Its just different approaches, List/Fetch is probably more common because of the way you can distribute the listing results across a cluster

Comment: Hmm ok. Also, the IdentifyMimeType did not work either... my processors are not throwing errors, and I have my IP address correct. Would there be any other reason the uploaded file would not read in?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "IdentifyMimeType did not work", what is the value of the mime.type flow file attribute right after the IdentifyMimeType processor?

Comment: As in I can't files to upload from SFTP to the AWS environment, where my NiFi container is located. So now this seems less of a NiFi problem and more of a getting machines to talk to each other correctly sort of problem